# Seeing the forest for the trees and all that jazz

Tags: pattern, lateral-thinking, number-sequence

No math involved here, just a bit of lateral thinking. Can you figure out what comes next?

> 2, 4, 8, 4, 4, 1, 3, 2, 7, 8, 3, 3, 6, 3, 4, 5...

**Bonus**: How about here?

> 6, 3, 6, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 4...

Comment: A comma comes next

Comment: And then a space would follow

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The first sequence:

> Each number in the sequence represents the number of letters in its respective sequential word in the sentence above. This makes the next (and final) number in the sequence:
>
>  **4**: from *"next"*

---

Edit: Thanks to @alexmc for the bonus part:

> Using the same method as in the first sequence, but with the words from the title, we can count the letters and see that the next (and final) number in the bonus sequence is also:
>
>  **4**: from *"jazz"*

Comment: Bonus is referencing the title - so 4

Comment: @alexmc you literally posted that a second after I posted my answer to it D:

Comment: Haha - shouldn't have gone back to add the hyphen....

Comment: I appreciate that this was marked as accepted because it was first, but maybe you want to flush out your answer so it doesn't seem like you were just trying to race to the finish line.

Comment: I gave @alexmc credit for the rest of the answer, but I can understand it because you deserve more upvotes than I do, having solved all of it by yourself.

Comment: Tried to delete it, but apparently accepted answers can't be deleted.

Comment: No, you should keep your answer. Just try to make it a little more "answery".

Answer (score 15):

You can see that the next number in the first sequence is **4**.

```
No math involved here, just a bit of lateral thinking. Can you figure out what comes next?
2  4    8        4     4    1 3   2  7       8         3   3   6      3   4    5     ...
                                                                                     4
```

The bonus also has **4** as the next number in the sequence.

```
Seeing the forest for the trees and all that jazz
6      3   6      3   3   5     3   3   4    ...
                                             4
```